# Xamarin Forms: BLE Laerdal Dfu OTA. compilation problems

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, ota, dfu

I am trying to get an App to work with OTA Nordic Dfu, and the only xamarin nuget I can find was the one made by Laerdal on [GitHub](https://github.com/Laerdal/Laerdal.Dfu/)

When I try to build under iOS I am getting a few error like this one here:

```
Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _TtC13iOSDFULibrary11DFUFirmware. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC13iOSDFULibrary11DFUFirmware' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
```

A [bug](https://github.com/Laerdal/Laerdal.Dfu/issues/17) is open for this, but so far not a word from the people maintaining it.

I am left wondering if this is actually a local problem and not a problem with the nugget its self. So if any one out here is able to compile this under iOS help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's a problem with the nuget itsself, it cannot be compiled using modern tools. When you visit the iOS native lib repo you'll see they have fixed compilation issues with Xcode 13 etc, so one needs to bind the latest native lib instead of outdated legacy.

Comment: If I were you I would bind it inside a maui lib to avoid another legacy issue with xamarin in the near future..

Comment: I used the build.sh script to recompile it locally. no change. As far as MAUI, I can't migrate to it as BLE nuget/libs are not good, plus the migration tool does not work on mac.

Comment: For maui you can use nuget AppoMobi.Maui.BLE with open source on github, i used for a maui app, published and working ok.